# How to parse an XML document with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to parse an XML file using Nokogiri in Ruby on Rails:

```
<ItemID>
    <SupplierPartID>GH-CF-BINDER</SupplierPartID>
  </ItemID>
  <ItemDetail>
    <UnitPrice><Money currency="USD"></Money></UnitPrice>
    <Description xml:lang="en">Ghent Contract Furniture Binder</Description>
    <UnitOfMeasure>Each</UnitOfMeasure>
    <Classification domain=""></Classification>
    <Extrinsic name="tag">GH-CF-BINDER</Extrinsic>
    <Extrinsic name="bin_number">103/18/9</Extrinsic>
    <Extrinsic name="billing email"></Extrinsic> 
    <Extrinsic name="bill_code6"></Extrinsic> 
    <Extrinsic name="prodcode"></Extrinsic>
    <Extrinsic name="stock_tag"></Extrinsic> 
    <Extrinsic name="has_imprint">N</Extrinsic> 
    <Extrinsic name="manuf_id">4117</Extrinsic>
    <Extrinsic name="bill_code1"></Extrinsic>

  </ItemDetail>
```

When I try to parse, instead of receiving a blank value for some blank fields, it instead returns the "name => bill_code1" (for example).

So far my solution is like this but every XML file is slightly different in the layout of the extrinsic tags:

```
item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'] = item_info_to_xml['ItemOut']['ItemDetail']['Extrinsic']

#expands from the above param extrinsic_tag because there is 10 elemenets in it
item_info_params['tag'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][0]
item_info_params['price'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][1]
item_info_params['bin_number'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][2]
item_info_params['requested_delivery'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][3]
item_info_params['billing_email'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][4]
item_info_params['bill_code6'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][5]
item_info_params['prodcode'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][6]
item_info_params['stock_tag'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][7]
item_info_params['has_imprint'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][8]
item_info_params['manuf_id'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][9]
item_info_params['bill_code1'] = item_info_params['extrinsic_tag'][10]
item_info_params['order_id'] = order.id

customer = Customer.create(item_info_params)
```

So, as stated above, `item_info_params['bill_code1']` will be assigned to `name => bill_code1` instead of a blank value.

It's confusing how to solve this problem.

Comment: @mudasobwa doesn't work. Gives the error  "NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for {"name"=>"bill_code1"}:Hash"

Comment: how are you converting it to Hash in the first place?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon the extrinsic tag itself is a hash. But "customer = Customer.create(item_info_params) is passing all the variable into customer as a hash.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need a syntactically correct, minimum example of your code. There's not much we can do to help you with varying XML format. You'll have to examine what you get and determine if you can write one script to account for the differences, or multiple scripts. That's out of scope for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

EXTRINSIC_NAMES = ['tag', 'bin_number', 'manuf_id']

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
      <ItemDetail>
        <UnitPrice><Money currency="USD"></Money></UnitPrice>
        <Description xml:lang="en">Ghent Contract Furniture Binder</Description>
        <UnitOfMeasure>Each</UnitOfMeasure>
        <Classification domain=""></Classification>
        <Extrinsic name="tag">GH-CF-BINDER</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="bin_number">103/18/9</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="billing email"></Extrinsic> 
        <Extrinsic name="bill_code6"></Extrinsic> 
        <Extrinsic name="prodcode"></Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="stock_tag"></Extrinsic> 
        <Extrinsic name="has_imprint">N</Extrinsic> 
        <Extrinsic name="manuf_id">4117</Extrinsic>
        <Extrinsic name="bill_code1"></Extrinsic>

      </ItemDetail>
EOT

item_detail = doc.at('ItemDetail')

extrinsic_values = EXTRINSIC_NAMES.map { |name| 
  [name, doc.at("Extrinsic[name=#{name}]").text]
}.to_h

extrinsic_values 
# => {"tag"=>"GH-CF-BINDER", "bin_number"=>"103/18/9", "manuf_id"=>"4117"}
```

Modify `EXTRINSIC_NAMES` to select which values you want.

If you want them all then it can be more simple:

```
extrinsic_values = doc.css('Extrinsic').map { |node| 
  [node['name'], node.text]
}.to_h

extrinsic_values 
# => {"tag"=>"GH-CF-BINDER",
#     "bin_number"=>"103/18/9",
#     "billing email"=>"",
#     "bill_code6"=>"",
#     "prodcode"=>"",
#     "stock_tag"=>"",
#     "has_imprint"=>"N",
#     "manuf_id"=>"4117",
#     "bill_code1"=>""}
```

Either way, if your XML files are not formatted the same then you'll have to allow for that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = '<ItemID><SupplierPartID>GH-CF-BINDER</SupplierPartID><ItemDetail><UnitPrice><Money currency="USD"></Money></UnitPrice><Description xml:lang="en">Ghent Contract Furniture Binder</Description><UnitOfMeasure>Each</UnitOfMeasure><Classification domain=""></Classification><Extrinsic name="tag">GH-CF-BINDER</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="bin_number">103/18/9</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="billing email"></Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="bill_code6"></Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="prodcode"></Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="stock_tag"></Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="has_imprint">N</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="manuf_id">4117</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="bill_code1"></Extrinsic></ItemDetail></ItemID>'


doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
bill_code = doc.xpath('//*[@name="bill_code1"]')[0].content
puts "bill_code: #{bill_code}"
#=> bill_code: 





tag = doc.xpath('//*[@name="tag"]')[0].content
puts "tag: #{tag}"
#=> tag: GH-CF-BINDER
```